# TkMessageBox - No Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

```
import TkMessageBox
```

When I import TkMessageBox it displays the messsge *'ImportError: No module named 'TkMessageBox'*.

As far as I know im using python 3.3.2 and Tk 8.5.

Am I using the wrong version of python or importing it wrong ?

Any answers would be extremely useful. Alternatively is there something similar in the version i am using?

Comment: do you want a messagebox Output?

Comment: `import TkMessageBox` => `from tkinter import messagebox`. Then use it like `messagebox.askokcancel(...)`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In Python3.x things have changed a little bit:

```
   >>> import tkinter
   >>> import tkinter.messagebox
   >>>
```

I mean what we call `tkMessageBox` in Python2.x becomes  `tkinter.messagebox` in Python3.x

Comment: ... so you can invoke like: `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations", "You won!")`

Comment: Care to explain your action? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939967/pattern-matching-instanceof

Comment: Sorry, I had to read your question more carefully. I voted to re-open your post and I upvoted it @Trey

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to have to change the code for Python 2 vs Python 3, you can use import as:

```py
try:
    from tkinter import messagebox
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox
```

:edit:
However, tkinter is in a separate package in Debian due to Debian policies causing code above to fall back to Python 2 incorrectly. So **instead, you should do**:

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
    from tkinter import messagebox
else:
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox
```

Then using messagebox as follows will work in either version:

```py
messagebox.showerror("Error", "Message.")
```

Answer (score 8):

In Python 2.x, to import, you'd say `import tkMessageBox`. But in Python 3.x, it's been renamed to import `tkinter.messagebox`.

Hope it helped :))

Answer (score 4):

**for python 3.x**

> import tkinter
>
> import tkinter.messagebox

Answer (score 0):

from tkinter import messagebox sous Python 3
messagebox.showinfo(title=None, message=None, **options)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thanks you for your contribution, but please provide further explanations on your solution: don't just give a fix, explain what it does and what was wrong