# How to overcome error message "java: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 8"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-18

code

```java
package org.example;

public class PatternSample {

    static String formatter(Object o) {
        String formatted = "unknown";
        if (o instanceof Integer i) {
            formatted = String.format("int %d", i);
        } else if (o instanceof Long l) {
            formatted = String.format("long %d", l);
        } else if (o instanceof Double d) {
            formatted = String.format("double %f", d);
        } else if (o instanceof String s) {
            formatted = String.format("String %s", s);
        }
        return formatted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatter("3.33"));
    }

}
```

error message

```
java: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 8
```

[image]

Comment: The feature was released in Java [16](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) and should work in Java [18](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html). As per the error message are you sure that your project is configured for Java 16 source or newer, the error message suggests its setup for Java 8 source. Also related: [Pattern matching instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939967/pattern-matching-instanceof)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to change to Java 16 in this particular case, although it's certainly an option to do so.

`String.format` actually takes `Object` arguments after the pattern, so you don't need to cast `o` to the various different types, which is what the "extended `instanceof`" actually does.  Just remove identifiers from the `instanceof` checks, and pass `o` as the argument to each call to `format`.  So you'll have something like this.

```
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        formatted = String.format("int %d", o);
    } else if (o instanceof Long) {
        formatted = String.format("long %d", o);
    } else if (o instanceof Double) {
        formatted = String.format("double %f", o);
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        formatted = String.format("String %s", o);
    }
```

Comment: In fact, it isn’t even necessary to use an expensive `String.format` call. A plain `String formatted = o instanceof Integer? "int " + o: o instanceof Long? "long " + o: o instanceof Double? "double " + o: o instanceof String? "String " + o: "unknown";` would do. No need to know whether to use `%d`, `%f`, or `%s` here (not that it matters much, as `%s` would do for all of them anyway).