# Using instanceof in if statement

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, instanceof

```
if(objectName instanceof Mammal currentMammal){
    currentMammal.shedHair();
```

if the (objectName instanceof Mammal) is true then currentMammal is casted to Mammal.
I see this works, but dont know how.
I have never seen this stuff going on in "if" statements

I believe this makes sense.

```
if (ao instanceof Mammal) {
    Mammal currentMammal = (Mammal) ao;
    currentMammal.shedHair();
}
```

but this first snippet is over my head

Comment: This was added in Java 14:  https://openjdk.org/jeps/305

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html the compiler effectively translates your first snippet into your second (the first is sugar for the second).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an identifier required for instanceof pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446857/why-is-an-identifier-required-for-instanceof-pattern-matching) Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939967/pattern-matching-instanceof

Answer (score 2):

The first one is just a syntactic sugar. Actually it do the `Mammal currentMammal = (Mammal) ao;` for you.

Answer (score -2):

Got the answer.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html#GUID-843060B5-240C-4F47-A7B0-95C42E5B08A7.

This is a new feature added in JDK 16.

Comment: I think the downvote/not upvoting happened because of .missing explanation. Also leaves a better impression leaving out "ChatGPT" and emoji. Just a tip. Nice reading of references